# Computer falls asleep "randomly" while using it and boots into Safe Sleep wake mode

Tags: sleep-wake

Ive got a weird issue happening on a 2012 15" Macbook Pro, the computer works fine for but every so often the screen will just go black and the machine goes into sleep. As it goes to sleep my screen goes black, but the cursor remains on screen for c. 10 seconds, before it disappears too.

I can wake the machine after about 30 seconds and it gives me the [Safe Sleep wake progress bar](https://support.apple.com/en-za/HT201635) overlaid on the screen i was last on.

Any idea how i can see what caused my machine to sleep ?

I hope it wasnt the GPU issue on the 2012 machines, but this happened under normal browsing so nothing GPU intensive.

Im running OSX 10.11

Comment: Looks like a battery problem. Did you try resetting the SMC and NVRAM or PRAM? Would also help to check the cycle count.

Comment: @Nimesh Neema , i have been having battery issues, although im currently plugged into the mains when this happened. The battery issues im having are related to the battery not holding enough charge, i got another battery sent out and the machine didnt recognise it after waking form sleep. I have an appointment booked in for later this week at the genius bar to hopefully resolve.